# How can I apply more than two options using toggle button in android?

Tags: android, button, togglebutton

I want to develop multiple button into one button. For example, I have the options like, Yellow, Red and Blue. If I click on button then first option will appear and screen become Yellow, then I again click on same button then screen become Red and if I again click on same button then screen become Blue.

Can anyone tell/suggest me how can I make multiple options button/ toggle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a RadioGroup with RadioButtons

Comment: But I want to show these options as a one option(button). I mean end-user can see only one option at a time. If he/she will click again then the other option will appear and the first one will gone

Comment: You want a 3 state thing. But I think there isn't a ready control for that. The alternative id that you use a single BUTTON (not toggle) and increase a variable each time it's clicked. If the variable gets > 2, the reset it to 0.

Answer (score 2):

This exact solution is not possible to achieve using only prebuilt controls in Android.

Here are your alternatives:

- Use a RadioGroup with several RadioButtons
- Use an Android-equivalent to iOS' UISegmentedControl like [this one](https://github.com/bookwormat/segcontrol)
- Build your own solution e.g. around a LinearLayout with Buttons
- Use a custom TriToggle like in [this](http://androidasilearnit.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/custom-toggle-button/) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a counter and a switch case in your onClick method. Declare the counter :

```
int mClickCounter = 0;
```

and do this inside onClick :

```
switch (mClickCounter){

    case 0: 
        mClickCounter = 1;
        // change screen color to yellow here
        // if needed, you could also change the text/color of the button 
        // to reflect the changing options 
        break;
    case 1: 
        mClickCounter = 2;
        // change screen color to red here
        break;
    case 2: 
        mClickCounter = 0;
        // change screen color to blue here
        break;
}
```